# split parameter pack in template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Is is possible to make `MyTemplate<Pack1<int>, Pack2<int, double>>::value` in the code works? Note that I'm not trying to write a type trait that checks if Pack2<...> starts the same as Pack1<...>. What I'm trying to do is to split the parameter of Pack2<...> into `Ts1` and `Ts2`.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename...>
class Pack1{};

template<typename...>
class Pack2 {};


template<typename...>
struct MyTemplate;

template<typename...Ts1, typename ...Ts2>
struct MyTemplate<Pack1<Ts1...>, Pack2<Ts1..., Ts2...>> {
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};


int main()
{
  // error: incomplete type is not allowed.
  std::cout << MyTemplate<Pack1<int>, Pack2<int, double>>::value; 
}
```

Comment: *"I'm not trying to write a type trait that checks if Pack2<...> starts the same as Pack1<...>"* But, once that is done, you might use `std::index_sequence` to iterate over `Ts2...` part which is not `Ts1...`.

Comment: You mean like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Eb8xP5W6v)?

Comment: @super: More like [that](https://godbolt.org/z/oa6cTdv1j) (completing Jan Schultke's answer).

Comment: @Jarod42 I was asking OP, to make him clarify his question. Until seeing the answer below and the comments, it's not really clear from the question alone that OP wants to remove the leading matching types from `Pack1/Pack2` and keep the trail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is flawed: you cannot deduce multiple template parameter packs from a single type, as you have attempted in `Pack2<Ts1..., Ts2...>`.
An obvious limitation is that the compiler can't know where to end one pack and begin the other. Even if `Ts1...` is deduced from another template argument, that can't mismatch the deduction elsewhere.

#### Possible Solution

```cpp
// Not sure why you've made two type lists; we only need one type.
template<typename...>
class Pack {};


// Let's give this trait a meaningful name: IsPrefix.
template<typename LeftPack, typename RightPack>
struct IsPrefix
  : std::false_type {};

// If the left pack is empty, it is a prefix of the right pack.
template<typename... Ts>
struct IsPrefix<Pack<>, Pack<Ts...>>
  : std::true_type {
    // As a side product of detecting prefixes, we can also obtain
    // a pack of all remaining types.
    using type = Pack<Ts...>;
};

// Otherwise, if two packs have a common prefix,
// remove that prefix and examine the rest.
template<typename Head, typename... Tail1, typename... Tail2>
struct IsPrefix<Pack<Head, Tail1...>, Pack<Head, Tail2...>>
  : IsPrefix<Pack<Tail1...>, Pack<Tail2...>> {};

// Otherwise, the base case is false.
// See inheritance from std::false_type in the primary template.
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PPsrh6a6a)*

You can then obtain the suffix as follows:

```cpp
using L = Pack<int, double>;
using R = Pack<int, double, float>;
using P = IsPrefix<L, R>;
if constexpr (P::value) {
    // P::type is Pack<float>
}
```

If you don't want to work with `Pack` in particular, you can also use template template parameters to make the `IsPrefix` trait work with any type list, including `std::tuple` and others.

Comment: From OP: *"I'm not trying to write a type trait that checks if `Pack2<...>` starts the same as `Pack1<...>`"*. So you have to complete to have access to tail of `Pack2`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not sure what case you think is missing from this trait. Do you mean that I need to use two different `Pack` types? My answer already addresses this; it looks irrelevant whether a single `Pack` type is used or two, so I have simplified that.

Comment: @JanSchultke I think the issue is removing the part from the second `Pack` that starts with what's in the first `Pack`. If `Pack1<int, double>` and `Pack2<int, double, float>` it should come out as `Something<float>` - if I understood it correctly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo only the first element is removed, so the case of `Pack<int, double>/Pack<int, double, float>` is transformed into `Pack<double>/Pack<double, float>` and then into `Pack<>/Pack<float>` which is a `std::true_type` base case.

Comment: It's the `<Pack1<Ts1...>, Pack2<Ts1..., Ts2...>>` and wanting to split it into `Ts1...` and `Ts2...` that makes me think that `Ts2...` should be all the types not covered by `Ts1...`. Could be wrong ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo OP said that it's a prefix check in their question, and their `MyTemplate` contains a `static constexpr bool`. The way that I see it, this is supposed to be a boolean type trait that checks if the left pack is a prefix of the right pack. I guess you could also obtain the remaining elements in the right pack; I'll note that in the answer.

Comment: _"I'm not trying to write a type trait that checks if Pack2<...> starts the same as Pack1<...>. "_  doesn't sound like a prefix check and - _"What I'm trying to do is to split the parameter of Pack2<...> into Ts1 and Ts2."_ makes it sound like extracting `Ts2`  is the goal - but, I'll stop guessing now :-) It'd be better if OP came in and cleared it up.

Comment: I didn't mean to have different Pack types, but having the addition `IsPrefix<LHS, RHS>::type` (a way to have the `Ts2...` of OP) :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah, I scanned OP's question and missed the *not*. I guess it all worked itself out in the end, because my trait also yields the suffix as a side product in `type`.

Comment: yeah, the goal is extracting Ts2.

Comment: @W.H That's cool and Jan said _"my trait also yields the suffix as a side product in `type`"_ so I get that's what you picked up on.

Comment: @JanSchultke Dropped out for bit.  I'd like to upvote this nice depickling. Can you add how to get the `Ts2...` to the answer? Just to make the side product clear.

Comment: There you go! +1